# JPA generated id causing a database object unknown error when trying to update sequence

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using a JPA repository to save an object to the database. Within my @Entity class, I have this identifier field

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence-generator")
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private Long addressId;
```

When I try save the entity, the JPA creates this SQL for the sequence generator:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2022-06-14 09:03:35.836--ClientSession(xxx)--Connection(xxx)--UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [50, sequence-generator]
```

And this results in the exception below. Even when I try this sql in my Dbeaver IDE, I get a -204 error which is a database object doesn't exist error. It says 'SEQUENCE' doesn't exist in my schema. How do I resolve this?

```
Internal Exception: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SMBGLOBAL.SEQUENCE, DRIVER=4.25.13
Error Code: -204
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [50, sequence-generator]
```

Comment: Did you try this `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="sequencegenerator")`?

Comment: You re missing the @SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq",sequenceName="MY_SEQ")